# Update PeerDependencies to Grunt 1.0

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to install `grunt-sass` but this is the error, I have gotten below about peerDependency needs to be updated.

[image: Installation of grunt-sass]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `grunt-autoupdate` needs to fix it's peerDependency http://gruntjs.com/blog/2016-04-04-grunt-1.0.0-released#peer-dependencies
But I think you already filled an upstream bug https://github.com/erwanjegouzo/grunt-autoupdate/issues/5